Error CS8618 in Product.cs file given below . im connecting MS Entity framework core with mysql , have created but its giving me an error in consle

PM> Add-Migration "Initial migration" Build started... Build
succeeded. The exception 'Host 'fe80::2095:47b:c9f:2e38%7' is not
allowed to connect to this MySQL server' was thrown while attempting
to find 'DbContext' types. For the different patterns supported at
design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

have tried and make sure hostname of database is same , provide it the port, and also double chek the code . the only error in code that is highlighted from bottom is this the Name and Type in this code :
Products.cs
namespace WebApplication3.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}


CS8618 is a warning, not an error - but it sounds like the problem you're facing has nothing to do with that, but is really about the migration.
